# CKEditor renders HTML tags inserted in wysiwyg mode to actual output in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor 4.5.3. I am having a serious problem as title of this post sounds. I explain it further - when I put HTML tags in CKEditor wysiwyg mode like below:

```
This is a <h1> heading tag.
```

In source mode, it converts to:

```
<p>This is a &lt;h1&gt; heading tag.</p>
```

So everything seems to be fine at this stage.

I am using PHP/MySQL to save all this information in the database. In my MySQL database, the above information is stored as:

```
<p>This is a &lt;h1&gt; heading tag.</p>
```

On front-end of my website, the information is shown as:

```
This is a <h1> heading tag.
```

So everything is again OK at this phase.

But when I open this post in my admin panel for editing purpose, the whole mess begins at this point. The wysiwyg mode of CKEditor displays the information stored in my database as:

[image]

Clearly, the HTML tag `<h1>` has been actually converted into heading output itself rather than showing it as a tag. So if I update the post, the browser output on front-end is eventually converted to:

[image]

I don't understand where is the problem - whether it is in CKEditor or something related to PHP/MySQL?

How can I prevent all this from happening?

**EDIT**

The HTML form field for which CKEditor is applied:

```
<tr>
    <th><label for="txtpostcontent">Content:</label></th>
    <td><textarea name="txtpostcontent" id="txtpostcontent" class="txtafield editor"><?php echo $post_content; ?></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Some PHP code:

```
// Here we fetch the content from database and store in a variable
$post_content = $post[0]->post_content;

// Here we print the array which stores the information from database
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_id] => 9
            [post_name] => HTML Headings
            [post_url] => html-headings
            [post_content] => 

this is a <h1> heading.





            [post_date_published] => 2016-02-22 15:54:51
        )

)

// On editing, we store the post content in a variable
$post_content = isset($_POST['txtpostcontent']) ? $_POST['txtpostcontent'] : '';
```

Note:
There is no AJAX is used in this process. The form is submitted in a regular fashion.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: I did it already as much as possible, however please ask what do you want to know further?

Comment: Show the code that renders the CKEditor form field

Comment: Like, for example, if you are using ajax when you hit the edit button...If that is the case, then I want to see the json server response...also how are you pass the data to the CKEditor...with this I can make a test sample on jsfiddle

Comment: @aross, I updated my question with some code example.

Comment: @Hackerman, there is no AJAX or JSON involved. It's a regular form submission on page reloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide an example, but I'm going to go off on a limb and say it's encoding. Consider this HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="Some HTML: <h1>">
```

Calling `jQuery('input:first').val()` will result in this: `Some HTML: <h1>`

Then this HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="Some HTML: &lt;h2&gt;">
```

The same JS will result in this: `Some HTML: <h2>`. This is not intuitive, right? There's the root of your problem. Consider this:

```
<input type="text" value="Some HTML: &amp;lt;h3&amp;gt;">
```

Now, the JS will result in what we want: `Some HTML: &lt;h3&gt;`.

To make sure your CKEditor gets the right HTML code, you will have to call [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) on the HTML before inserting it in your input's `value=""`.

In your case, you're using a textarea, so it may be slightly different. But I found a [blog post](https://usolved.net/blog/post/ckeditor-converts-html-entities-to-angled-brackets) that came to the same conclusion as I for a similar (the same?) problem: a syntax highlighting plugin messed up encoding, so he had to convert htmlentities (the author of the blog post chose to convert only `&lt;` and `&gt;`, not sure if that matters).

Comment: Oh @aross! you are overthinking. Why did you take concept to jQuery? There is no jQuery or AJAX involved in storing and displaying information. Simple form is submitted on page loading and textarea (CKEditor) value is stored in database. But when it is fetched back from database the HTML tags (that were stored in htmlentity) are started rendering in wysiwyg mode of CKEditor.

Comment: You misunderstand, it has nothing to do with jQuery, I just gave a code example in jQuery to illustrate the problem. I could just as easily have done that with JS. And CKEditor is pretty heavy on JS. But even that is beside the point.

Comment: @user5307298 are you using a syntax highlighter plugin? I updated my answer with another possible scenario. It still boils down to encoding though...

Comment: No syntax highlighter plugin. I fixed the problem by using htmlentities() to show the textarea content in ckeditor window. But no idea why it did it work even without this function in one of older version of CKEditor. Who knows?

Comment: I don't know. But if my answer helped, please accept it.

Comment: I did. Thanks! That trick to use htmlentities() was really helpful.